# Приостановить программу до заполнения текстового поля

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть поле ввода InputField. Как приостановить выполнение программы до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет данные в это поле и не нажмет ввод?

Comment: условием... что не понятно?

Comment: Я не буду на колене писать для вас код с нуля, напишите что у вас уже готовое есть.

Answer (score 0):

```
Btn.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
if(InputField.Text != ""){
//есть текст
}else{
//нету текста
}};
```

как то так... "Btn" твоя кнопка,

Comment: Какая кнопка? Он в вопросе о кнопках не упоминал

Comment: @SeeSharp кнопка "Ввод" я так понял это Enter тогда `public void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) //условие }`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поместить начало программы в какой-то метод и поместить этот  метод сюда[image: inputfield]

Он выполниться как только вы нажмете энтер в вашем поле для ввода